# jenkins parallel streams with local files?

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins, jenkins-pipeline

My parallel steps need access to a local file in the workspace of the job. But it seems they can access it?

I tried listing the workspace in each stream:

```
powershell "ls ${workspace}"
```

they are all empty! the output of each stream `ls C:\workspace\branch_name@<stream#>` shows no files.

How they get access to the workspace? they're pretty much useless to me if they can't even access local files.

Is there a feature to copy files from the main workspace to the stream workspaces?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The way you handle this in Jenkins is to stash and unstash the files for each parallel job.

https://jenkins.io/doc/pipeline/steps/workflow-basic-steps/#code-stash-code-stash-some-files-to-be-used-later-in-the-build

Answer (score 0):

Since [Powershell support was recently introduced](https://jenkins.io/blog/2017/07/26/powershell-pipeline/), and there is a [powershell step](https://jenkins.io/doc/pipeline/steps/workflow-durable-task-step/#code-powershell-code-powershell-script) ([issue JENKINS-34581](https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/browse/JENKINS-34581)), do check you are in the same path each time:

```
node {
     powershell '$(pwd).Path'
     bat 'echo %cd%'
}
```

And that you have checked out a repository first (or your workspace would be empty anyway)

Comment: I need to recheckout my whole repo for each stream? How do I just copy specific files from the main pipeline workspace to the streams workspaces

Comment: @red888 In that (Kubernetes) setting, you need for your podTemplate to mount a volume (PersistenceVolumeClaim done beforehand: https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/storage/persistent-volumes/#persistentvolumeclaims)